# I installed STS 3.9.9 in my eclipse and I made a Simple Spring Maven project, but it is empty. How can I get the proper template?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, project, spring-tool-suite

I installed STS 3.9.9 in the eclipse and made a Simple Spring Maven project in the Spring legacy project folder.

However, it just creates a project with a file called MANIFEST.MF. It is missing the template that includes the src folder, web folder and etc.

How can I properly create a complete Simple Spring Maven project?

Am I missing anything?

Thank you,

Comment: I tried a fresh install of the STS 3.9.11 distribution and it seems to create the project just fine, so hard to say exactly what is going wrong there. In case you don't use a distribution of STS 3.9.11 (and installed components into Eclipse manually), maybe the Maven Integration for Eclipse is missing. But since this is the Legacy project creation wizard, I would strongly recommend to switch to a newer version of the tooling (Spring Tools 4) and create new Spring projects using the Spring Starter wizard, which integrates https://start.spring.io into the IDE. Definitely the way to move forward.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I could not figure out this problem, but it is okay now. Thank you again!

Comment: Did you try to download a ready-to-use Spring Tools 4 distribution and start from there via the wizard to create a new maven-based spring boot project? Would strongly recommend that.